# Replace text written in one column based on the content of another column?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file. In one sheet of it, I want to replace all text written in one column (for example M) based on the contents of another column (for example K)?  I mean:

for all data written in column M which are NULL :

> If K(n) = 0 Then M(n) = ' '
>   If K(n) = 1 Then M(n) = 'unlimited'
>   If K(n) = 2 Then M(n) = ' '

Comment: Sorry, but I deleted my answer since you would have to create a 3rd column with formulas to insert into column M, but there is now way I know to do that in Excel.  Worksheet functions in Excel work on the cell itself (or a range of cells starting with that cell).  You would have to use VBA to do what you want.  You also need to specify better what you do want, because not all cases are covered, and your text didn't describe things as well as your comment on my answer, but that didn't cover all the cases.  Good Luck.

Comment: So for each blank cell in a column, you want to run a series of `if` cases based on a cell in the corresponding `row`?

Answer (score 0):

You description is unclear, however, it appears that you are only putting 'unlimited' in the blank cells of column M if the corresponding value in column K is 1. If column M actually contains the text 'NULL' rather than being blank/empty, then the following won't work.

- Highlight the data in column M and chose the Home tab, Find & Select Group, and 'Go To Special' (or use Ctrl-G, Special..)
- Choose Blanks. This will select all blank cells in this range
- Type the following formula, using the mouse to click on the corresponding cell in column K. That is, for the same row of the currently active cell.

  =IF(K12=1,"unlimited","")

You need to press Ctrl-Enter to fill this formula in all the currently selected cells.

When complete, I assume that you'll want to highlight column M and Copy/ Paste-Special, Values.